# ByPassing System Files Permissions VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, exception, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I started making a file manager which scans a folder selected by user through **folderbrowserdialog** in vb.net, extract the extentions of every file in every directory or subdirectory using **GetFiles()** Method with **SearchOption.AllDirectories**. I am having an **UnauthorizedAccessException** when it scans the **Recycle Bin** Folder in logical drive whereas i have seen Softwares like **WinRar** or **R-Studio** Scanning and showing every directory without having an exception or error. Following is my code:

```
Public Sub WriteExtentionsToFile()
    Try
        Title_Window.FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()
        Dim Path As String = Title_Window.FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath

        'Getting FilesNames

        Dim FileNames As String() = GetFilesNames(Path)
        Title_Window.LblStatusBar.Text = "File Names Saved"
        Dim MaximumForProgressBar As Integer = FileNames.Length
        Title_Window.ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = MaximumForProgressBar
        Title_Window.ToolStripProgressBar1.Step = 1

        'Getting Extentions

        Dim ExtentionsList As New List(Of String)
        For Each item In FileNames
            ExtentionsList.Add(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(item))
        Next

        'Deleting Duplicate Extentions

        Dim NoDuplicateExtentionList As New List(Of String)
        Dim ExtentionReadFromFile As String() = ReadExtentionsFromFile()'Another Function in my Class Which Reads previously saved extentions in a file and store them in an array
        For Each item In ExtentionReadFromFile
            NoDuplicateExtentionList.Add(item)
        Next
        For Each E In ExtentionsList
            Dim LastIndexOfDot As Integer = E.LastIndexOf(".")
            E = E.Remove(0, LastIndexOfDot + 1)
            If NoDuplicateExtentionList.Contains(E.ToLower) = False Then
                NoDuplicateExtentionList.Add(E.ToLower)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("d:\ExtentionsList.txt", E.ToString & vbCrLf, True)

            End If
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Writing Process Completed", "Success")

    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        Dim Buttons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore
        Dim result As DialogResult
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Access Denied", Buttons)
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
          'What should be Done Here????
        ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
         'What should be Done Here????
        Else
         'What should be Done Here????
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

What should be the solution for thsi problem? Is this about getting the permissions through FileIoPermission Class or something else??

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting to bypass permissions.  Just ignore the folders you don't have access to, either by catching exceptions or by rolling your own recursive filesystem reader.

Comment: You can't by-pass windows security. If you could, security would be pretty useless!

Comment: Well whats the process to ignore the exception? what is the code? i cant get it anywhere, i have the code for scanning the files recursively but no ignoring the exception.